# Unity how to add horizontal force to your rigidbody only. Vertical force gets applied

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

im trying to add horizontal force to my player. But everytime I try, only Vertical force gets applied. My character shoots straight in the air but not to the left or right. I also tried adding way more force.
Maybe im doing something wrong idk.

```
public class SpaceScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Rigidbody2D Player1 = Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        Player1.AddForce(new Vector2(10, 10), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

    }
```

Comment: The y-axis is the up axis in unity.  By providing `Vector2(10, 10)` you are moving in both the x and y axes.

Comment: The strange thing is, when I set the y-axis to 0, and the x-axis to 100, it wont move at all. thx for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

To eject the player into one direction (x-axis) you need way more force than pushing him in the air (y-axis) and I deleted `, ForceMode2D.Impulse)`.Now it works perfectly fine.

Comment: It is important to understand why this resolves the issue, and the reason is because of how the different force modes work.  `ForceMode2D.Impulse` is useful for explosions and collisions, as it adds an instant force to the rigidbody.  `ForceMode2D.Force` applies a gradual force over time, making it ideal for more realistic physics.  Both take mass into account.  ForceMode2D.Force is the default force mode when none is provided.